# How to paste HTML into a CS class

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

My ASP.NET MVC app sends an email to users once they have created an inventory along with the PDF file for them to download. I have created a HTML form so people dont get just a bad looking text but a nice email.

I have tried pasting the html where I put ("here") in the following string

`var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, to, subject, "Correo generado por Elyssa, se ha generado un inventario.", "("here")");`

So far I am getting +99 errors in the console and I dont really know whats going on, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should show the resulting code, don't just describe it by saying you put it "here".

Comment: @mason I am not sure what you mean with the resulting code. I meant that I pasted the 64 lines of HTML where I put "here" so I dont put all the code in this question.

Comment: Put it all in the question, or at least a snippet of it that still demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I put an @ before the string and it ran as expected. Thanks for the time anyway man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an @ before the string, it will instruct the compiler to interpret the string literally. My best guess is that the compiler is assuming you have character escape sequences and is 'busting up' your HTML string.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it worked perfectly. Highly appreciate!